# How to display a table as a search result using Angular?

Tags: angular, search

I am using this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-search-filter-functionality-on-entire-table?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch.pipe.ts) code to use search functionality. I want to do little modification. On page load I just want to display only search box (not table) and the searchbox should populate when you type letters and then when you select one of the items then the table should display with the related record or records.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It is just like Google search...when you search..the results will be displayed...but I want to dsiplay in tabular format

Comment: For the first part of your problem "On page load I just want to display only search box (not table)", just add `*ngIf="email != ''"` on your `table` element, for your second problem, I don't understand sorry

Comment: also in the search box...when you type in Google ..."USA P"...something like it will display the values in searchbox like usa president ,usa presdinet 2021 etc so that you can pickup one automatically reslts will be displayed